# Field fetched through REST API contains ASCII version of special characters

Tags: rest-api

The title of my WP `about` page contains apostrophes. When I fetch that page through REST API from my Vue.js frontend, the apostrophes in the title become ASCII characters.

How to avoid this?

(and why is the title also contained in some `rendered` sub-property?)

The `/wp/v2/pages/?slug=about` REST API route returns:

```
{
  ...,
  title {
    rendered: "Who&#8217;s this?"
  }
}
```

[image]

Instead of this ASCII mess, it should simply be: "Who's this?"

For the record, in my Vue.js frontend I'm fetching this REST API route thus:

```
axios
  .get('/wp/v2/pages/?slug=about')
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response.data[0])
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Instead of this ASCII mess, it should simply be: "Who's this?"

No, it should not.

If you make a `OPTIONS` request to the `/wp-json/wp/v2/pages` path, you'll see the [schema](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/pages/#schema) which defines all the fields that exist within a Page record, like so for the post title field, via JavaScript's `fetch()`:

- [image: Screenshot 2]
- [image: Screenshot 1]

Therefore, `title.rendered` is meant for display and thus, filters like [`wptexturize()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wptexturize/) ( which converts the `'` to `&#8217;s` ) are applied to the raw post title.

- See [`WP_REST_Posts_Controller::prepare_item_for_response()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_posts_controller/prepare_item_for_response/) which uses [`get_the_title()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/) which applies the filter hook [`the_title`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_title/).
- See also [`WP_REST_Posts_Controller::get_item_schema()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_posts_controller/get_item_schema/) which defines core post/page record's fields.

If you want to get the raw post title, you can use `/wp/v2/pages?slug=about&context=edit`, i.e. set the `context` parameter to `edit`, and read the raw title via `title.raw`, but [authentication](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/) is required.

- Alternate options (apart from disabling the texturize filters): filter the schema or modify the REST API response, or create a custom REST field which would return the raw title. But then, it is up to you to decide on the most appropriate option in your case. ✌

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Soo we can get the (filter-free) post content but God forbid we get the title.. I mean this makes absolutely zero sense to me, is it not obvious that most people will want to display the post title not just the post content? Why making things so ridiculously convolutated? I don't get it.

Comment: Actually, the raw or actual database values of the guid, title, content and excerpt, are by default only made available when `context` is `edit`, that is when the request is authenticated and the current user is authorized (e.g. (s)he can edit posts). When the context is view (which is the default), the values you see would all be filtered for (safe) display/render, e.g. via the `the_content` filter for the `content.rendered` field. But as I said, you could filter the schema if you wish to allow public access on the raw data like `title.raw`.

Comment: OK but that doesn't really justify why we can so easily access/display the post content whereas the post title requires to take separate, relatively complicated steps - such difference makes no logical sense to me. Anyway thanks but even after googling it I have no idea what 'filtering the schema' means..